How can I add customized color to mat-buttons?
I need to use this mat-button in Angular project, how can I usee customized color instead of accent, primary, etc.
<button (click)="gotoDashboardHome()" mat-raised-button color="accent" class="centered-button">
            <mat-icon>reply</mat-icon>
            <span class="button-text">Back</span>
        </button>

.centered-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
 
.button-text {
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

Customizing mat-buttom colors

I think you should be able to tamper with which color is your primary secondary color etc. by tampering with your src/styles.scss file, for instance you can do this:
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

$custom-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$custom-accent: mat-palette($mat-pink);
$custom-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

$custom-theme: mat-light-theme(
  $custom-primary,
  $custom-accent,
  $custom-warn
);

@include angular-material-theme($custom-theme);

Then you should be able to use the color like that:
    <button (click)="gotoDashboardHome()" mat-raised-button color="custom" class="centered-button">
  <mat-icon>reply</mat-icon>
  <span class="button-text">Back</span>
</button>

